# How to pass two parameters in a post request?

Tags: java

I have a post request being sent in the following manner:

```
final private ObjectMapper mapper;
...
...
Response response =target.request().post(Entity.entity(mapper.writeValueAsString(feedbackFilterDataForDA),
                    APPLICATION_JSON));
```

And the request goes to a function of type:

```
public Response getData(FeedbackFilterDataForDA f,ArrayList<String> a) {
}
```

How should I change the post request to take both the parameters as input?

Answer (score 1):

I see three options:

- Enhance the JSON to include the additional information, e.g. by wrapping the current JSON in another JSON Object with 2 properties.
- POST the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`, with one of the values being the JSON payload.
- POST the data as `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`, with one part being the JSON payload.

Comment: Can you add how to use multipart/form-data with some example

Comment: @Nitika Yes, I can, but I'm not going to. Can you search the web?

Comment: Tried searching but no luck.

Comment: @Nitika Really? [`java multipart/form-data example`](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+multipart%2Fform-data+example) lists many examples.